# DNS nameserver with cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosting, cloudflare

I originally bought a domain from namecheap.com then I bought hosting at inmotionhosting, where I pointed the DNS from namecheap to inmotionhosting... now I signed up with cloudflare and pointed DNS to cloudflare instead of inmotionhosting... now since I've pointed it to cloudflare, do I really need inmotionhosting? Can't I stop paying for their service?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was DNS hosting the only thing you were using at inmotionhosting? If so, then yes, you should be fine ditching that service.

Comment: thanks for responding. Can I add both cloudflare DNS and inmotionhosting DNS to cheapname?

Comment: No. Well theoretically yes, but you don't want to so that. You need to choose one provider to be your authoritative dns host.